# Determining if 5 seconds have passed

Tags: c++

I'm trying to determine if five seconds have passed in a console application since the last time I checked. I think my logic is slightly off and I don't know how to resolve it.

My `lastCheck` variable is firstly 0 when the program begins. It's responsible for holding the "old time".

`LastCheck` is updated by `CheckSeconds()`, which gives it a new "old time"

If the `LastCheck` was equal to 1232323, and the `now` variable is currently equal to 1227323 then I would know 5000 milliseconds have passed. (in reality, the numbers are much greater than this)

Else, I don't want anything to happen, I want to wait until these five seconds have actually passed.

**BACKEND**

```
inline std::vector<int> CheckSeconds(int previous, int timeinseconds)
{
    //check if a certain amount of seconds have passed.
    int now = GetTickCount();
    int timepassed = 0;
    std::vector<int> trueandnewtime;
    //if the current time minus the old time is greater than 5000, then that means more than 5000 milliseoncds passed.
    //therefore the timepassed is true.
    if (now - previous > 5000)
        timepassed = 1;

    trueandnewtime.push_back(timepassed);
    trueandnewtime.push_back(now);

    return trueandnewtime;

}
```

**FRONTEND**

```
storage = CheckSeconds(LastCheck, 5);
        LastCheck = storage.at(1);

        if (storage.at(0) == 1)
        {
            ....blahblahblah.....
        }
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I must have a logic error somewhere or I'm being dumb.

Also worth noting, this code is in a while loop, getting constantly run at `Sleep(60);` It's a console application at the momemnt.

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Is `int` large enough to store the result of `GetTickCount`?

Comment: use the functions in [#include <chrono>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) for checking the time, and use an operating system function for sleeping

Comment: int is large enough, otherwise it would show weird values whilst debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by putting the Lastcheck set into the loop.